# R ggplot2 facet_wrap() with scales = "free", but each panel having fixed

Tags: r

I want to produce a figure that will have several scatterplots.  Each scatterplot should have its own axis limits, but I want the aspect ratio of each plot to be 1 so that the 1:1 line goes through the plot at a 45 degree angle.

Here's an example of what I have going on:

```
 met <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(946756800, 946756800, 946756800,946756800, 946756800, 946756800, 946756800, 960465600, 960465600,960465600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Met_Parameter = c("1/MO l","albedo", "Bowen r", "conv mix h", "mech mix h", "MO l", "sens h flux","wind s", "wstar", "z0"), `Original Met` = c(0.0746268656716418,0.15, 0.8, -999, 24, 13.4, -0.7, 4, 1.2, 1), `Converted Met` = c(-0.0105263157894737,0.15, 0.8, 600, 367, -95, 21.6, 4, 1.2, 1)), row.names = c(1L,2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1054L, 1055L, 1056L), class = "data.frame") 

pOUT <- 
  ggplot2::ggplot(data = met,
                  aes(x = `Original Met`,
                      y = `Converted Met`)) +
  ggplot2::geom_point()+
  ggplot2::geom_abline(intercept = 0,
                       slope = 1
                       ) +
  ggplot2::facet_wrap("Met_Parameter",
                      scales = "free") +
  ggplot2::ggtitle("Comparison of Original Meteorology Versus Up Over Down Meterology") +
  ggplot2::theme_bw()
```

What I am missing still is how to make the x and y axes fixed within the plot.

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258095/facet-with-free-scales-but-keep-aspect-ratio-fixed. Looks like the only solution thus far is to make individual plots and paste together with `cowplot` or any other plot aggregating package

Comment: I think this answer might help you. I think what you are really trying to do is use facet_wrap with a coord_fixed ratio 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549294/get-same-height-for-plots-having-different-facet-numbers-and-coord-fixed